# Airflow best practice : s3_to_sftp_operator instead of running aws cli?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ftp, airflow

What would be the best solution to transfer files between s3 and an EC2 instance using airflow?
After research i found there was a **s3_to_sftp_operator** but i know it's good practice to execute tasks on the external systems instead of the airflow instance...

I'm thinking about running a bashoperator that executes an aws cli on the remote ec2 instance since it respects the principle above.

Do you have any production best practice to share about this case ?

Answer (score 1):

The `s3_to_sftp_operator` is going to be the better choice unless the files are large. Only if the files are large would I consider a bash operator with an ssh onto a remote machine.  As for what large means, I would just test with the `s3_to_sftp_operator` and if the performance of everything else on airflow isn't meaningfully impacted then stay with it.  I'm regularly downloading and opening ~1 GiB files with `PythonOperator`s in airflow on 2 vCPU airflow nodes with 8 GiB RAM.  It doesn't make sense to do anything more complex on files that small.

The best solution would be not to transfer the files, and most likely to get rid of the EC2 while you are at it.

- If you have a task that needs to run on some data in S3, then just run that task directly in airflow.
- If you can't run that task in airflow because it needs vast power or some weird code that airflow won't run, then have the EC2 instance read S3 directly.
- If you're using airflow to orchestrate the task because the task is watching the local filesystem on the EC2, then just trigger the task and have the task read S3.